# WebOS Logging PDK on emulator

Tags: logging, emulation, webos, pdk

How can I log runtime information from a native application running on the WebOS emulator. I just need to get some output from the emulator. I've used the badfont example.  I've SSH:d into the emulator and used

```
tail -f /var/log/messages | grep com.palmdts.app.badfont
```

but the log does not show anything. In the application I've added

```
#include <syslog.h>

openlog("com.palmdts.app.badfont", 0, LOG_USER);

and 

syslog(LOG_INFO, "Logging %i", 1);
```

But the log is empty. All I want is to get some way of printing runtime information

Comment: Seems that I just had to move the openlog() command to be called elsewhere than the main method. Works fine now.